# Woocommerce Align Price Elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, sass

Currently My Price Elements are unaligned. I am trying to align them no matter the size of the title above them. I have tried different methods using Flexbox to get this result, but have not figured out a solution. Current Progress below. This is what it currently looks like [Current styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifEUq.png) Any Direction would be appreciated.

```css
   // Product
        li.product {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: calc(100% - #{$base-spacing});
            margin: 0 $base-spacing/2 $base-spacing;
            padding: em($base-spacing);
            background: $white;
            text-align: center;
            transition: all $base-duration $base-timing;
            border: 5px solid transparent;

            // Sale Icon
            span.onsale {
                background-color: $primary-color;
                height: 4em;
                width: 4em;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            // Product Image
            img {
                width: auto;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-bottom: em($base-spacing);
                transition: all $base-duration $base-timing;
                height: 220px;
            }

            // Product Name
            h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
                margin-top: 0;
                padding: 0 em($base-spacing);
                font-family: $base-font-family;
                font-weight: 700;
                text-transform: capitalize;
                font-size: em(18);
                color: $base-font-color;
            }

            // Price
            .price {
                font-size: em(22);
                color: $primary-color;
                margin-top: $base-spacing/2;
            }

            @include xs-up() {
                width: calc(50% - #{$base-spacing});
            }

            @include md-up() {
                width: calc(33.3% - #{$base-spacing});
            }

            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                border: 5px solid $primary-color;

                //a.add_to_cart_button {
                //    background-color: $secondary-color-dark;
                //}
            }

            .button.add_to_cart_button,
            .button.product_type_simple,
            .button.product_type_external,
            .button.product_type_grouped,
            .button.product_type_variable {
                position: relative;
                margin-top: $base-spacing*2;
                @include hollow-button();

                @include md-up() {
                    float: none!important;
                }
            }

            // target external products
            &.product-type-external {
                .button {
                    white-space: normal;
                }
            }

            // target grouped products
            &.product-type-grouped {

            }

            // target variable products
            &.product-type-variable {

            }
        }
```

```html
<li
    class="product type-product post-18183 status-publish first instock product_cat-halloween-masks product_cat-horror-movies has-post-thumbnail taxable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
    <a href="https://screamerscostumes.test/product/a-nightmare-on-elm-street-deluxe-freddy-krueger-mask-with-fedora-hat/"
        class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"><img width="300" height="369"
            src="https://screamerscostumes.test/app/uploads/2021/10/RLWB106-noes-freddy-withhat-1-300x369.jpg"
            class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt=""
            srcset="https://screamerscostumes.test/app/uploads/2021/10/RLWB106-noes-freddy-withhat-1-300x369.jpg 300w, https://screamerscostumes.test/app/uploads/2021/10/RLWB106-noes-freddy-withhat-1.jpg 499w"
            sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">A Nightmare on Elm Street – Deluxe Freddy Krueger Mask with Fedora
            Hat</h2><span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span
                        class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>99.99</bdi></span></span>
    </a><a href="?add-to-cart=18183" data-quantity="1"
        class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="18183"
        data-product_sku="RLWB106"
        aria-label="Add “A Nightmare on Elm Street - Deluxe Freddy Krueger Mask with Fedora Hat” to your cart"
        rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a></li>
```